# Laravel call service with repository pattern from other service

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using [repository pattern](https://medium.com/employbl/use-the-repository-design-pattern-in-a-laravel-application-13f0b46a3dce) in my Laravel project.

what is the good pattern to call service from other service?

For example service will looks like this:

```
class GetAllUsersService 
{
    private $userRepository; 

    public function __construct(UserRepository $repository)
    {
       $this->userRepository = $repository;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
       return $this->userRepository->getAll();
    }
}
```

Now if I want to execute this service from other part of the application I will do something like this:

```
class AnyClass
{
   public function executeUserService()
   {
      $repository = new UserEloquentRepository();

      $service = new GetAllUsersService($repository);

      return $service->execute();
   }
}
```

Is it correct way to do it? Is there other ways? Maybe some UI layer should be in between?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have three ways to do it:

1) use method __construct();

```
class AnyClass
{
    private $get_all_users_service;

    public function __construct(GetAllUsersService $get_all_users_service) 
    {
        $this->get_all_users_service = $get_all_users_service;      
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $fetchAllUsers = $this->get_all_users_service->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

2) use the specified services like a parameter of each function needs to use them:

```
class AnyClass
{
    public function index(GetAllUsersService $get_all_users_service)
    {
        $fetchAllUsers = $get_all_users_service->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

3) use method app() of Laravel helper like this:

```
class AnyClass
{
    public function index()
    {
        $get_all_users_service = app(GetAllUsersService::class);

        $fetchAllUsers = $get_all_users_service->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: the first approach will not fit my case, the I will have to pass the repository to `AnyClass`, second one will also say that you have to pass service to `index` function. But third one looks great!

Comment: nice it is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

for php 8.x

```
    class AnyClass
    {
        public function __construct(protected GetAllUsersService $get_all_users_service) 
        {
            
        }
    
        public function index()
        {
            $fetchAllUsers = $this->get_all_users_service->fetchAll();
        }
    }
```